# Error in publishing PowerBI dashboard with R script

Tags: r, powerbi

I need to publish my dashboard from PowerBI and there is some graphics made with R, in the desktop application works just fine. The problem comes when I try to publish it. I get this error:

[image]

Here's one of the codes that doesn't even uses the functions "filter()" ou "lag()"

```
pacotes <- c("dplyr", "tidytext", "ggplot2","stopwords", "wordcloud")

if(sum(as.numeric(!pacotes %in% installed.packages())) != 0){
  instalador <- pacotes[!pacotes %in% installed.packages()]
  for(i in 1:length(instalador)) {
    install.packages(instalador, dependencies = T)
    break()}
  sapply(pacotes, require, character = T) 
} else {
  sapply(pacotes, require, character = T) 
}


negative <- dataset$aspects
negative <- tibble(text = negative)
df <- negative %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)

df <- df %>% anti_join(get_stopwords(language = 'pt'))
df_cont <- df %>% select(word) %>% count(word, sort = TRUE)
pal <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("#365D8DFF", "#27AD81FF"))(6)
df_cont %>% with(wordcloud(word, n, random.order = FALSE, 
                           max.words = 30, colors=pal,
                           scale = c(3,1.25)))
```

Comment: The warning about filter and lag is normal, and always happens with dplyr. With your code, it would be useful to add one line at a time till you encounter the error, so we know what line is failing. One cause would be if `dataset$aspects` is a factor, rather than character. `class(dataset$aspects)` would shed light on this. `dataset$aspects <- as.character(dataset$aspects)` would help if aspects is a factor. Hope this helps Diogo! :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try following your suggestions, for that I must be authorized by my leader in the company. But if it work, I'll let you know and thank you again here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the exact solution, but here was the problem:
I didn't wrangled my dataset in powerbi 'cause it would take too many steps, so I did it inside the R visual, as you can see in the code before the plotting. Now, I wrangled my dataset with R in the power query (taking just one step), and with these news dataframes I created I could finnally plot in the dashboards with PowerBI visuals.
Moral of the story: R Visual is for plotting only, data wrangling is in Power Query.
See ya!